Ubuntu 24.04 update hides files
I updated Ubuntu 24.04 this morning with sudo apt-get update. That worked OK:
Fetched 34.2 MB in 49s (696 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

Now I cannot find or access my home directory:
root@LAPTOP-AOP0ANAK:~# cd home
-bash: cd: home: No such file or directory
root@LAPTOP-AOP0ANAK:~# ls -al
total 24
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Oct 30 06:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Oct 30 06:22 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Oct 15  2021 .bashrc
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Aug 21 06:10 .cache
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Oct 30 06:22 .motd_shown
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  161 Jul  9  2019 .profile
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Aug 21 06:10 snap​

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

There is no directory called home. You have /home which is the default directory under which user home directories are stored. So, for example, user mary would have their home directory at /home/mary.
You might be thinking of $HOME, that is a variable that is set to point to your home directory, so you could try cd $HOME. That's kind of pointless though since cd alone will move you to your home directory anyway.
In your case, you seem to be logged in as the root user for some reason. The root user's home is /root, so not even under /home. More to the point, you are already in your (i.e. root's) home directory, as can be seen by the presence of the .bashrc and .profile files and also by the fact that your prompt shows ~ in the place where you have the directory name:
root@LAPTOP-AOP0ANAK:~#
                     ^
                     |------> that is the directory

The tilde, ~, is used as a shorthand for your $HOME.  So you have nothing else to do, you are already in the home directory.
My guess is that you forgot you are logged in as root, and you want to go to your regular user's home. Just exit the root shell (run exit) and that should take you back to your regular user. If not, perhaps you have logged in as root graphically so in that case, just log out and log back in.
More generally, if you want to move to the current user's home directory, all of these should do the same thing:
cd
cd ~
cd $HOME


Yes, somehow I got logged in as root when it should be rich@LAPTOP-AOP0ANAK:~#  I am very new at Linux.  How do I change to rich from root?

As I explain in the answer, run exit or log out graphically. Since you haven't explained how you became root, I can't be more specific.

Sorry, I am very new at Linux.  I am running WSL on a Windows 10 laptop and it used to open in my directory, rich.  Now it opens in root.  When I run exit as you suggested, the WSL screen just shuts down.  I have tried the commands login and su - rich, but neither work.

@richs I'm sorry but that's a whole different issue. Please ask a new question, this time mentioning that you are not using an actual Linux system but instead are using WSL, explain what you need and someone who knows WSL (I don't) might be able to help.
